# Comparing Array fields for Nulls,Equal,Not equal - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

**Table Name: customers**

```
customer_id   Profiles      dept_code
------------------------------------------   
3361           ,15,31,4,     ,01,02,
3362           ,32,          ,01,03,
3363                         ,04,
3364           ,1,20,21,     ,01,02,03,
```

**Table Name :customers_backup**

```
customer_id   Profiles       dept_code
--------------------------------------
3361           ,15,31,4,      ,01,02,
3362           ,32,33,34,     ,01,03,
3363           ,10,           ,04,
3364           ,1,20,21,      ,01,02,03,
```

I am trying to update the PROFILE of CUSTOMERS table and the conditions are given below,

1) If customer profile is NULL => update customers_backup profile

2) If customer profile equal to customers_backup profile => just keep customer 
   profile
3) If customers profile <> to customers_backup profile => Keep customer profile and append the profile from customers_backup that is not in the customers table.

I need the following output :

**Table Name: customers**

```
customer_id   Profiles      dept_code
------------------------------------------------   
3361           ,15,31,4,       ,01,02,
3362           ,32,33,34,      ,01,03,     ( How to apply this condition?)
3363           ,10,            ,04,
3364           ,1,20,21,       ,01,02,03,
```

Below is what I wrote for condition 1 & 2. But they don't give the expected result.

```
update customers set profiles=
CASE WHEN (select unnest(array[customers.profiles])) is null 
      THEN customers_backup.profiles 
 WHEN (select unnest(array[customers.profiles])) = 
      (select unnest(array[customers_backup.profiles])) 
      THEN customers.profiles
 WHEN (select unnest(array[customers.profiles])) <> 
      (select unnest(array[customers_backup.profiles]))  ---  Need help here
 THEN user_enrollment_backup1.profiles 
END FROM customers_backup 
WHERE customers_backup.customer_id=customers.customer_id
AND customers_backup.dept_code= customers.dept_code;
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data type  are those columns? They don't look like arrays. Rather like text columns with comma separated values

Comment: It's select multiple field in the interface and the data is stored like the above in table.

Comment: I hope we can trim the commas at the beginning and end and treat them as an array. Should that work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use actual arrays, you need to clean up your data first so it's in the correct format -- i.e. no leading/trailing commas.  Once you have this, you can CAST your `profiles` field as an array data type and use array concatenation, similar to this:

```
SELECT 
  ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(customers.profiles || customers_backup.profiles))
FROM ...
```

This should combine your array elements into one array, then unnest & remove duplicate elements, and then finally combine back into the final array.  I don't think they will be ordered, but this should get you started.

It looks like your `profile` values are not real arrays, so you'd need to CAST them as arrays in the query above.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an `UPDATE` table `FROM` syntax.
Note that arrays can be compared using `=` and `<>` operators.
Only for finding the union (3rd case ), you could use `UNNEST`.

```
UPDATE customers AS c 
SET profiles = CASE WHEN c.profiles IS NULL 
    THEN cb.profiles
   WHEN array[c.profiles] = array[cb.profiles] 
    THEN c.profiles
   WHEN  array[c.profiles] <> array[cb.profiles] 
    THEN ( select string_agg(a,'')
             from (
                select distinct 
                  unnest(array[RTRIM(c.profiles,',')::VARCHAR] || array[cb.profiles]) as a
            ) s 
          )          
   END
FROM customers_backup as cb
WHERE c.customer_id = cb.customer_id;
```

Also note that If you `create extension intarray,` you may use simple | operator for array UNIONs.

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9be3d/1)